# Bash History: Default size should be 500 but getting 1000

Tags: bash, bash-history

As [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/624848/view-history-of-commands-ran-in-terminal?noredirect=1&lq=1) suggest that bash keeps last 500 entries in history. But following command suggest otherwise,

```
$ echo $HISTSIZE
1000
```

I have never changed bash history settings or config files other than to edit path variables.
I am using Ubuntu 14.04 amd64 .

Comment: reference for this environment variable: http://askubuntu.com/questions/624848/view-history-of-commands-ran-in-terminal?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `HISTSIZE` environment variable is not set in any startup configuration file of `bash`, it will be set to 500. From `man bash`:

> The shell sets the default value to 500 after reading any startup
>   files.

The `HISTFILESIZE` follows `HISTSIZE`, if not set.

Now, you are getting the value of `HISTSIZE` as 500 because Ubuntu by default sets the `HISTSIZE` (and `HISTFILESIZE`) environment variables to the following values in your `bash` runtime configuration file (the file that will be `source`-d when a new interactive shell instance is started), `~/.bashrc`:

```
# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)                                                                                                                     
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000
```

---

To be sure, read the `.bashrc` skeleton file, `/etc/skel/.bashrc`; It is copied to each newly created user's `bash` runtime configuration file, `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Yup ~/.bashrc contains HISTSIZE=1000 and HISTFILESIZE=2000.