# View terminal history without the line number

Tags: command-line, bash, history, bash-history

How can I get the Ubuntu terminal history without the **line number**?

```
history
```

`history` command returns the previous commands with line number. I am looking for something like:

```
 cd tizen-sdk\tools          
 ls
```

instead of

```
924  cd tizen-sdk\tools      
925  ls
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `fc` command instead. From `help fc`:

```
fc: fc [-e ename] [-lnr] [first] [last] or fc -s [pat=rep] [command]
    Display or execute commands from the history list.

    fc is used to list or edit and re-execute commands from the history list.
    FIRST and LAST can be numbers specifying the range, or FIRST can be a
    string, which means the most recent command beginning with that
    string.

    Options:
      -e ENAME  select which editor to use.  Default is FCEDIT, then EDITOR,
            then vi
      -l    list lines instead of editing
      -n    omit line numbers when listing
      -r    reverse the order of the lines (newest listed first)
```

Therefore:

```
fc -ln
```

You can also look at the history file directly, but it might not be updated:

```
cat "$HISTFILE"
```

Comment: + OP's question, is there a way to tell to do not record line number in history file?

Comment: @KasiyA the history file does not record line numbers (it only records commands, and if `HISTTIMEFORMAT` is set, timestamps).

Comment: Will it display all history?

Answer (score 2):

Use this command:

```
history | cut -c 8-
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html).

```
history | awk '{$1=""; print}'
```

Comment: You can use `awk '{$1=""}1'`