# Finding an old command in the shell history

Tags: command-line, bash, history, bash-history

How can I find an old command I ran in my terminal?

I used an appengine command and wish to just find it in my local command history without researching it online again.

Comment: Run `history` in terminal or if u remember some parts of the command  `history | grep <command-parts>`, but note if you have made other commands and ure history settings in `.bashrc` is not large then you might never see it.

Comment: Not sure it's worth a full answer... but you can also hit the ~/.bash_history file in your editor of choice ie: `vim ~/.bash_history` and search inside the file/editor.

Comment: Related: [View history of commands ran in terminal](http://askubuntu.com/q/624848/301745)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[**History**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man3/history.3tcl.html) is what you are looking for.

Run `history` to get a list of the last 1000 commands, or run:

```
history | grep command_to_search
```

to search some pattern within the history generated list, for example:

```
history | grep apt
```

To search any `apt` related command, note that `grep` does not anchor your pattern to either end of the string, so no wildcards needed in most cases.

---

The `history` **list is generated from** the last 1000 commands (by default) stored in **`~/.bash_history`** (which stores the last 2000 by default), and such file gets only updated whenever you exit your Bash session cleanly. That means, all commands from your current session will not be in that file until you close your terminal. They will also not be written if you kill the shell process.

Therefore, the command history (2000 last commands) can also be found at `~/.bash_history`, by either:

- `less ~/.bash_history` or, e.g. `gedit ~/.bash_history`
- Opening Nautilus, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>, and searching for the `.bash_history` file.

---

Both `history` and `~/.bash_history` behavior **can be changed** by adding or modifying the options in `~/.bashrc`, these are a few examples:

- Append `export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups` or modify the existing `HISTCONTROL` line,  to remove duplicate commands, i.e. if one runs `echo Hello` immediately after `echo Hello`, only one will appear in `bash_history`.
- Modify `HISTSIZE=1000` to extend or reduce the amount of commands shown with `history`
- Modify `HISTFILESIZE=2000` to extend or reduce the amount of commands stored in `bash_history`. Set `HISTFILESIZE=-1` for unlimited.
- Append `HISTFILE=/path/to/file` to save the history somewhere else.

---

Sources and further reading:

[Bash man pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/bash.1.html)

[Credit to comments from Byte Commander](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897127/finding-an-old-command-in-the-history#comment-1405342)

Comment: `grep apt*` does not what you think it does. First, the `apt*` will be processed by Bash's filename globbing, so if you have any files in your current directory that start with "apt", the glob will be replaced with them and `grep` would only search for those full filenames. To prevent globbing, wrap the pattern in double- or better single-quotes: `grep 'apt*'`.

Comment: But this is still not what you want, because `grep` treats the pattern as regular expression, and in regular expressions, a `*` means "match the previous character any time, including zero" - so the pattern would match "ap", "apt", "aptt", "apttt" etc. You could write `grep 'apt.*'`, because the `.` in a regular expression matches any character, but this is superfluous because `grep` does not anchor your pattern to either end of the string, so just write `grep 'apt'` and you will be good.

Comment: Note also please that `~/.bash_history` gets only updated whenever you exit your Bash session cleanly. That means, all commands from your current session will not be in that file until you close your terminal. They will also not be written if you kill the shell process.

Comment: However, enough bashing for today. Your answer is nice other than those few points and I see you already started editing it to fix them. So have a +1 and hopefully you learned something today :)

Comment: Yes I am learning indeed, thanks a lot for taking that time to explain. Just added the extra info :)

Comment: @ByteCommander, re. `grep apt*` without any quotes, I made a small text file with the following strings, one per line: 
ap 
appointment 
appearance 
apt 
aptly 
aptitude 
aptness . 
Then I ran `grep apt*` on that file. The only hits were (one word per line): 
apt 
aptly 
aptitude 
aptness

Comment: @DKBose Could you possibly have had any file called `apt` in your current directory?

Comment: Wow.. Tot I ask a simple question but am wow by the quality of answers.. And details about history and bash_history files.. Reverse search etc... Clearly written essays.. God bless you guys.. This has been the best responses I have ever received

Comment: @ByteCommander, yes! That was the name I gave that small file! I will try again with another name.

Comment: @ByteCommander, I did the same thing in an empty folder but this time calling the file `test.txt` and got exactly the results with `grep apt*`, `'grep apt*'` and `"grep apt*"` as you predicted. Thanks!

Comment: It's not so much as "grep command_to_search" as it is "grep text_to_find" - it should search more than just "commands". `history | grep zcvf` will find `tar -zcvf file.txt`. You could also throw the `~/.bash_history` file into an editor and find the commands that way.

Answer (score 15):

There are many ways to find an recently executed command.

- The most simple one is to just hit the <kbd>↑</kbd> key and cycle through your command history line by line until you spot what you looked for.
- You can also press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to enter the so-called `(reverse-i-search)` mode.

  It is a search prompt that will automatically complete what you start to type with the most recently run command that contains this string. When it shows what you looked for, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run it, or <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit the search prompt while keeping the command on the prompt, so that you can edit it. To discard the result and exit search, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
- You can use the `history` Bash built-in to show the complete list of recorded commands from your history.

  You can filter that list for lines matching a specific pattern using e.g. `grep`, like `history | grep 'appengine'`.

  More info about the `history` built-in command of Bash can be found by typing `help history`.
- Use bang-expansion to directly run the most recently executed command containing a string. This will replace the line you typed with the matching line from history and run it immediately, without confirmation, so be careful.

  Simply type `!string` and it will replace that with the most recent command-line that started with "string".

  If you want to run the last command that ended with "string", type `!?string` instead.

  Or if you want the last command-line containing "string" anywhere, type `!?string?`.

  More info about history bang expansion can be found by typing `man history`.

Comment: Wow.. Tot I ask a simple question but am wow by the quality of answers.. And details about history and bash_history files.. Reverse search etc... Clearly written essays.. God bless you guys.. This has been the best responses I have ever received

Comment: Always glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

If it was somewhat recently used it may be easy for you to find it by opening a terminal and using the up and down arrows on your keyboard to go through your last used commands.