# "The following packages have unmet dependencies" Error

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I tried to install a package through apt-get but I get this error. I've tried many solutions including ones in askubuntu but none worked and things are just getting worse and I get more `<package>: Depends: ...`

Please help me. I really don't know what do you. I just installed this new Ubuntu. This error is making me old. Isn't this a bug?

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 account-plugin-facebook : Depends: libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth but it is not going to be installed or
                                    ubuntu-system-settings-online-accounts but it is not going to be installed
 account-plugin-flickr : Depends: libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth but it is not going to be installed or
                                  ubuntu-system-settings-online-accounts ...
```

A brief history:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
sudo apt-get install lib32ncurses5
sudo apt-get install multiarch-support
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-gtk
sudo apt-get  install libgtk2.0-0:i386
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-gtk
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-gtk
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch
dpkg --add-architecture i386 
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
apt-get install libc6:i386 
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386
sudo apt-get install libpangoxft-1.0-0
sudo apt-get install libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386
sudo apt-get install libpangox-1.0.so.0
sudo apt-get install libpangox-1.0.so.0:i386
sudo apt-get install classicmenu-indicator
sudo apt-get install python
sudo apt install python-pip
sudo pip install tensorflow-gpu
pip install tensorflow
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev
sudo apt-get install python-dev # (first time I noticed the unmet error(but probably was getting that from a few commands before this. I see the word Depends 4 times in its result(if i'm not mistaken))
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt install aptitude
sudo aptitude install python-dev
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install libpython-dev
sudo apt-get install libpython2.7-dev
sudo apt-get install libpython2.7-stdlib
sudo apt-get install libpython2.7
sudo apt-get install libpython2.7-dev
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo apt-get install python-dev
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
mkdir ppa-purge && cd ppa-purge && wget http://mirror.pnl.gov/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/ppa-purge/ppa-purge_0.2.8+bzr56_all.deb && wget http://mirror.pnl.gov/ubuntu//pool/main/a/aptitude/aptitude_0.6.6-1ubuntu1_i386.deb && sudo dpkg -i ./*.deb
sudo ppa-purge ppa:someppa/ppa  
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install python-dev # (still getting the unmet error. I see the word Depends 525 times in its result).
```

Comment: Don't use random apt incantations blindly. That can make things worse. Read the error message. Ask yourself *why* those packages won't be installed.  Try installing one or two and see what happens.

Comment: @user535733 I have 525 `Depends` in that error. It was 4 before I made it worse.  I'm not an apt expert. I don't want to reinstall this Ubuntu. It was a few hours ago I installed this Ubuntu. What is your opinion? What should I do?

Comment: You say *I just installed Ubuntu*, well then, just reinstall again, you will avoid some headaches.

Comment: @M.Becerra It toke me several hours to "personalize" it. I had that error in my previous Ubuntu. And I'm pretty sure that I'll have that error in my next Ubuntu (never gonna happen!). So.. I think something here is wrong and I wanna know what that is.

Comment: If you always get this even after a fresh install, the problem must be those "personalization" things you do. If you could add a detailed list to your question, it would be VERY helpful to diagnose.

Comment: Your customizations likely caused the problem. Seems like you added non-Ubuntu sources that, in turn, introduced incompatible software. Reinstall, keep good notes, and test for incompatibilities like these after each apt step. When you discover the bad customization, undo it.

Comment: @Milad you have two options: You can learn apt so you can debug the problem, or you can stick closer to the stock Ubuntu install to avoid the problem. Repeatedly breaking your system the same way seems a waste of your time.

Comment: @M.Becerra I don't always get that error right after installing Ubuntu. I'm using Ubuntu for 3 years now. But it was always my problem. This time I tried to install `Longman`(the dictionary) and I followed the instruction but I wasn't able to install it (problem with 64bit OS) and it was just a mess in apt-get world! And now I get that unmet error for installing `python-dev`.

Comment: @user535733 How can I learn `apt` so I can debug that?

Comment: *I don't always get that error right after installing Ubuntu.* Thats exactly my point. There must be something you usually do that keeps causing this problems. You can start learning `apt` by [edit] ing your question with the steps you followd when you wanted to install `python-dev`. If you cant remember, check this http://askubuntu.com/questions/897127/finding-an-old-command-in-the-shell-history

Comment: In order to figure out why you get the first error, we need to know what you did **before** being prompted with it, extend the history, please

Comment: The use of `aptitude` is recommended for a better understanding of tree dependecies.

Comment: @M.Becerra `aptitude` is not installed now (I think `apt-get install -f` removed it) and I can't install it because of the `unmet` error.

Comment: I'd guess the problem is related to adding the 32bit arch and installing SO MANY things for 32bits. I still suggest reinstalling, and doing whatever customization things you want, but cheking step-by-step, to igure out what breaks it

Comment: @M.Becerra So it's broke now? If I mess with apt-get I might have to reinstall my OS? I haven't executed any dangerous command. You think I can do anything except reinstalling my OS?

Comment: @Milad “I haven't executed any dangerous command.” Any command starting with `sudo` is potentially dangerous… Related: [How to remove the “unmet dependencies error” about cups while installing a package?](https://askubuntu.com/a/898059/250300)

Answer (score 0):

Wow, this was super easy, all I had to do was apt-get remove the dependency and install my target package.

For example...

```
account-plugin-facebook : Depends: libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth but it is not going to be installed or
                                    ubuntu-system-settings-online-accounts but it is not going to be installed
```

Simply do this

```
apt-get remove libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth
apt-get install account-plugin-facebook
```